# Wrong object creation in Angular post

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS controller, which looks like this:

```
function MainController($scope, $http) {
    //code for HTTP Get
    $scope.SelectionChanged = function () {
        //some initialization code
        $http.post("/api/cinema", { film: $scope.film })
            .then(function (result) {
                //success
            }, function (result) {
                //failure
            });
    }
}
```

SelectionChanged is a function that binds to scope in order to make some select elements responsive.

I can see in fiddler that the object passed is something like:

```
{"film":["HO00000335"]}
```

but what i would expect would be:

```
{"film":"HO00000335"}
```

How can i do that?

Eidt:

Right now when i make a selection in my list i get the following in fiddler:

```
POST http://localhost:18669/api/cinema HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:18669
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 23
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:18669
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:18669/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

{"film":["HO00000262"]}
```

Comment: Firstly change your `$scope.SelectionChanged = function SelectionChanged() {` to `$scope.SelectionChanged = function() {`

Comment: What is the value of `$scope.film`? If you drop a `console.log($scope.film)` inside `SelectionChanged` what is the output?

Comment: It should be HO00000335

Comment: @jyparask I know what you *want* it to be, but what is it *actually*? You probably just need to specify `{ film: $scope.film[0] }`.

Comment: @AndréDion I don't know if my edit answers your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `$scope.film` is an array.

Try this:

```
function MainController($scope, $http) {
    //code for HTTP Get
    $scope.SelectionChanged = function () {
        //some initialization code
        $http.post("/api/cinema", { film: $scope.film[0] }) // note the [0]
            .then(function (result) {
                //success
            }, function (result) {
                //failure
            });
    }
}
```